# C#(UWP)からPythonスクリプトが実行できない

Tags: python, c#, visual-studio, uwp

VisualStudio2019、c#、UWPで、Pythonスクリプトを呼び出して実行したいのですが、
Web上で公開されているコードで試した結果、例外(アクセスが拒否されました。)が発生する。

参考にしたwebサイトは、https://www.gis-py.com/entry/csharp-py　です。

```
var pythonInterpreterPath = @"C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe";
var pythonScriptPath = @"D:\BW\tes01.py";
var arguments = new List<string>
{
    pythonScriptPath,
    "arg1",
    "arg2"
};

var process = new Process()
{
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(pythonInterpreterPath)
    {
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        Arguments = string.Join(" ", arguments),
        },
    };

    process.Start();
```

例外の詳細：

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception
  HResult=0x80004005
  Message=アクセスが拒否されました。
  Source=System.Diagnostics.Process
  スタック トレース:
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
```

Comment: UWPではProcess.Startは使えないようですが。[C#でコマンドを実行したい【UWPアプリ】](https://teratail.com/questions/214552) 「Process.Start メソッドは使えません。」, [DesktopBridge アプリで UWP アプリと Win32 アプリの連携方法](https://blog.okazuki.jp/entry/2018/02/10/174735), [ファイルに応じた既定のアプリの起動](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-the-default-app-for-a-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

すでに他の方の回答にある通りですが、以下の2つの制約から提示されているコードを実行するのは難しいように思います。

1. UWPのコードから直接Process.Startメソッドを使うことはできない
2. アプリパッケージ外の実行ファイルの起動は許可されていない

1の制約を回避するためには、まずFullTrustProcessLauncherで.NETアプリを起動させて、そこからProcess.Startを使う必要があります。
2の制約を回避するためには、PythonスクリプトをPyInstallerなどでexeファイル化しておく必要があります。

この辺の詳しい手順や注意事項、実際にMicrosoft Storeに提出したリファレンスアプリなどを記事にまとめましたので、もしよければご覧ください。
[UWPアプリにPythonでコーディングした処理を組み込む](https://biotech-lab.org/articles/9985)

Answer (score 1):

コメントで紹介した記事と、さらにその前段記事の組み合わせで動作させられるようです。
確認したわけでは無いのと2年前の記事なので変わっているかもしれないので、これらを参考に試してみてください。
ポイントになりそうなところを抜粋しておきます。詳細は記事を参照してください。

[Desktop Bridge のアプリで UWP から同じパッケージ内の exe を起動する方法](https://blog.okazuki.jp/entry/2018/02/09/204909)

> **プロジェクトの設定**
>   LaunchApp プロジェクトのアプリケーションの右クリックメニューから参照の追加で、LaunchApp.UWP と LaunchApp.WPF を追加します。
>
> **マニフェストへの exe の登録**
>   LaunchApp プロジェクトの Package.appxmanifest を右クリックしてコードの表示をします。
>   Package タグに以下の xml 名前空間を追加します。
>
> そして、Application タグの下に Extensions タグを以下のように追加します。
>   ここに登録した exe が起動できます。注意点は1つしか登録できないところですかね。（多分）
>
> **UWP から exe の起動**
>   まず、FullTrustProcessLauncher クラスを使うのですが、これはデスクトップデバイスファミリーのみで使えるので参照に追加します。
>   参照の追加で Universal Windows → 拡張 の中にある Windows Desktop Extensions for the UWP にチェックを入れます。
>
> exe を起動するきっかけのボタンを MainPage.xaml に置きます。
>
> MainPage.xaml.cs で以下のコードを書きます。
>
> FullTrustProcessLauncher.LaunchFullTrustProcessForCurrentAppAsync() で先ほど定義した Extension の exe が起動します。

[DesktopBridge アプリで UWP アプリと Win32 アプリの連携方法](https://blog.okazuki.jp/entry/2018/02/10/174735)

> 起動は出来たら次したいことは連携ですよね。ということでしてみましょう。
>   **仕組み**
>   UWP の AppService を使ってやるのがお勧めです。
>   [アプリ サービスと拡張機能の使用](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/uwp/launch-resume/app-services)
>   UWP 側で AppService を作っておいて、それを介して WPF などの Win32 アプリと UWP のアプリが連携するようにします。 なのでこんな感じで動くような雰囲気ですね。
>
> - UWP アプリ起動
> - Win32 アプリ起動
> - Win32 アプリから AppService へ接続
>
>   - UWP アプリ側で AppService が起動する
> - 接続を介してやり取り
>
> 私が最後に UWP を勉強したときは別プロセスで AppService が起動してたような気がするのですが最近は UWP アプリと同じプロセスで可能になっててびっくりしました。
>   [ホスト アプリと同じプロセスで実行するようにアプリ サービスを変換する](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/uwp/launch-resume/convert-app-service-in-process)
>   **App.xaml.cs の編集**
>
> **WPF 側の実装**
>   あとは MainWindow でクリックされたときに AppServiceConnection を作って繋ぎに行ってます。
>
> **コード**
>   プロジェクトは GitHub に公開しています。GitHub のほうのコードは、ここでのコードをちょっと改造して UWP -> WPF 方向の通信も追加しています。
>   [runceel/DesktopBridgeAppService](https://github.com/runceel/DesktopBridgeAppService)

---

ちなみに、起動する exe が UWPアプリのAppXフォルダ(UWPアプリと同じフォルダということ？)に入っている必要があるようなので、PyInstallerとかで exe 化した方が良いかもしれません。
[UWP LaunchFullTrustProcessForCurrentAppAsync - EXE file not found](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54686706/9014308)

> As Mentioned in the official sample the exe file has to in the Appx folder of your project
>
> > Make sure the RebootPC.exe was copied to the Appx folder - UWP\bin\x64\Release\AppX if not rebuild the solution or copy it manually.
>
> 公式サンプルで言及したように、exeファイルはプロジェクトのAppxフォルダーにある必要があります
>
> > RebootPC.exeがAppxフォルダー（UWP \ bin \ x64 \ Release \ AppX）にコピーされていることを確認します（ソリューションを再構築しない場合、または手動でコピーする場合）。

[DesktopBridgeToUWP-Samples/Samples/AppServiceBridgeSample/](https://github.com/Microsoft/DesktopBridgeToUWP-Samples/tree/master/Samples/AppServiceBridgeSample#builddeploy-and-run-the-sample)

他参考に。
[UWP：FullTrustProcessLauncher で起動したプログラムに引数を渡す](https://blog.daruyanagi.jp/entry/2018/06/09/163500)